# Update existing entity property values with array properties

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google Cloud Datastore in my project, and have thousands of entities already. I want to update existing values of a property (which is of type String) to Array Values. Basically i want that property to now hold 2 values - existing value and corresponding new value for all entities. Can we do that? I want to avoid a new kind which has mapping of existing to new one.
ex - From id  to  id
          10      10 20

Also i don't see Array Value API support in Entity class in GAE SDK 1.9.30. Is it added in 1.9.36?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using the App Engine SDK (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) to access Cloud Datastore?

Comment: Actually I used objectify approach (persistence model) to store data before, and have thousands of entities already in a datastore in say kind A. Now i want to update all the rows of one of the property of kind A, and make it of type Array Valued in one shot. How can i do it? i think will have to update each value using java datastore api?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how this would work in Objectify, but in the Java Datastore API, you can store properties of type `List` (this corresponds to an array value). Here's a code sample: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Repeated_properties. To do the migration, you'd have to update each entity.